# get special date columns that columns contain date,hour,seconds

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
 df=pandas.DataFrame([{'remarkTime':'2014-03-03  10:18','name':'a'},{'remarkTime':'2015-05-03  09:12','name':'b'},
                     {'remarkTime':'2014-03-03  18:12','name':'c'}])
```

I want get the remarkTime which is 2014-03-03. the result like this:

```
   name  remarkTime
0    a  2014-03-03
1    c  2014-03-03
```

firstly,I try use "==" or "in" to get the row. but the "==" isn't suitable for this situation.secondly, I try split the "2014-03-03  10:18". but It failed.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with comparing [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) with `date`. Last parse [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
#convert to datetime if necessary
df.remarkTime = pd.to_datetime(df.remarkTime)

print (df.remarkTime.dt.date == pd.Timestamp(2014,3,3).date())
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: remarkTime, dtype: bool

df = df[df.remarkTime.dt.date == pd.Timestamp(2014,3,3).date()]
print (df)
  name          remarkTime
0    a 2014-03-03 10:18:00
2    c 2014-03-03 18:12:00

df.remarkTime = df.remarkTime.dt.date
print (df)
  name  remarkTime
0    a  2014-03-03
2    c  2014-03-03
```